# detox is unable to mock

Tags: react-native, detox

I am using RN 59 and Detox 12. I have configured metro.config.js like so:

```
const defaultSourceExts = require('metro-config/src/defaults/defaults').sourceExts
module.exports = {
  transformer: {
    getTransformOptions: async () => ({
      transform: {
        experimentalImportSupport: false,
        inlineRequires: false,
      },
    }),
  },
  resolver: { 
    sourceExts: process.env.RN_SRC_EXT
      ? process.env.RN_SRC_EXT.split(',').concat(defaultSourceExts)
      : defaultSourceExts,
  },
}
```

I have api.js and api.e2e.js

Running `RN_SRC_EXT=e2e.js yarn start`, `RN_SRC_EXT=e2e.js ./gradlew assembleDebug assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug` and `RN_SRC_EXT=e2e.js detox test -c android.emu.debug` still results in `api.js` being used instead of `api.e2e.js`

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: Turned out I had the wrong file name. `apis.e2e.js` Notice the extra `s`

Comment: hm... I'll see if it's similar for me. Thanks!

Comment: is this config still working for you Amit

Comment: @robto09 haven't done any testing myself anymore since